# Reversing a sentence in Java without changing the character order using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, substring, reverse

I'm using this code to reverse the order of the sentence but what it does is reverse the order of characters too. Help me here so the characters do not get reversed, only words do.
e.g. "cat is running" --> "running is cat"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "Cat Is Running";
    System.out.println(reverse(sentence));
}

public static String reverse(String str) {

    if(str.isEmpty())
        return str;
    else {
        return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);    
    }
}
```

Comment: **Hint:** You also need some code that isolates the words.

Comment: Yes ofc, can u help?

Comment: **Hint:** String.split()

Comment: how would that be used?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Comment: Actually i was asking about the logic

Comment: When you use split() on your sentence (using a space as the delimiter), it will give you an array of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- you search for the last space `"Cat Is Running"`
- at the first iteration `SpaceIndex = 6`
- you print the part after the space which is `"Running"` and you call recurive
  the same method without that part (`"Cat Is"`)
- At the last iteration when space is not found you just output the
  string what you have.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String sentence = "Cat Is Running";
   reverse(sentence);
 }

public static void reverse(String str) {
   int spaceIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
   if(spaceIndex == -1){
     System.out.print(str);
     return;
   }
   System.out.print(str.substring(spaceIndex+1) + " ");
   reverse(str.substring(0,spaceIndex));
}
```